# Do I need any of the *variantType markers?

Tags: rust, ffi, type-safety

I'm trying to interact with a type-unsafe C library in a type-safe way from Rust. The C interface deals with some `void` pointers. Specifically, there is a `write` and a `read` function that takes such a `void` pointer as parameter and does the obvious things (write the given data to some place else or read from that place into the given buffer). What kind of data this is, is agreed upon earlier py bassing a certain integer value to an `open` function

```
1 = float
2 = int32_t
4 = int16_t
etc...
```

I represent an opened output stream (where the user can call write on) with a parameterized Rust struct like this one:

```
pub struct OutputStream<T> {
    c_stream: *mut ()
}

impl<T: ValueType> for OutputStream<T> {
    pub fn write(&mut self, data: &[T]) -> Result<(),SomeErrorType> {
        unsafe { ... }
    }
}
```

where `ValueType` is a trait I wrote for all the supported value types in a way that nobody else can implement it (private base trait trick). So, obviously T is not mentioned anywhere within the struct. It seems this is a case for the [ContravariantType](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/marker/struct.ContravariantType.html) marker. But I don't really understand these type markers. Visiting the wikipedia page on variance does not help. I just don't see the connection between variance and how this applies to Rust's type parameters. And I don't really know what this kind of marker would actually prevent.

So my questions are: Do I need one of these markers for my `OutputStream`? If so, which one and why? What exactly would I prevent by using it? The same goes for an `InputStream` which provides a `read` method instead of a `write` method.

Answer (score 1):

In general, variance determines subtyping relationship between parameterized types with regard to their parameters:

```
Covariance:      T <: U    =>    F[T] <: F[U]
Contravariance:  T <: U    =>    F[U] <: F[T]
Invariance:      T <: U    =>    neither of the above
Bivariance:      T <: U    =>    both of the above
```

Your type *is* naturally contravariant: its methods only *consume* values of type `T`, but do not *produce* them; this is so-called consumer type. However, subtyping in Rust is very limited; as far as I know, the only types which allow subtyping relationship of any kind are references (for example, you can pass `&'static str` into `&'a str` variable because `'static` lifetime is greater than or equal to any other lifetime, so `&'static str` is a subtype of `&'a str` for any `'a`).

So, if I understand correctly, you do need variance annotation. If your `T` parameter can be a reference, use `ContravariantType`, so you could do this:

```
fn push_something_to(os: OutputStream<&'static str>) { ... }

let s: OutputStream<&'a str> = ...;  // and 'a is less than 'static
push_something_to(s);   // this is safe to do because &'static str is valid &'a str
```

but couldn't do this:

```
let s: OutputStream<int> = ...;
push_something_to(s);   // oops, push_something_to expects stream of &'static str
```

With `InvariantType` both are forbidden.

---

However, there seems to be some deep misunderstanding on my side, because neither the code in the documentation on variance markers, nor my own code does not work in the current Rust for me:

```
use std::ptr;
use std::mem;

struct S<T> { x: *const () }

fn get<T>(s: &S<T>, v: T) {
   unsafe {
       let x: fn(T) = mem::transmute(s.x);
       x(v)
   }
}

fn main() {
    let s: S<int> = S { x: ptr::null() };
    get::<Box<int>>(&s, box 1);
}
```

According to the documentation, this should compile due to parameterized types being bivariant by default, but it doesn't: it acts as if the parameter is invariant.

And this is my own example:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

type F<T> = fn(T);

fn test_1<'a>(f: F<&'a str>) -> F<&'static str> {
    f
}

struct S<T> {
    _m: std::kinds::marker::ContravariantType<T>
}

fn test_2<'a>(s: S<&'a str>) -> S<&'static str> {
    s
}

fn main() {}
```

As far as I understand, this program should compile, but it doesn't:

```
<anon>:9:5: 9:6 error: mismatched types: expected `S<&'static str>` but found `S<&'a str>` (lifetime mismatch)
<anon>:9     s
             ^
<anon>:8:47: 10:2 note: the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 8:46...
<anon>:8 fn test<'a>(s: S<&'a str>) -> S<&'static str> {
<anon>:9     s
<anon>:10 }
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
```

If I remove `S` and `test_2`, it compiles fine, demonstrating that function types are indeed contravariant with regard to their argument types.

I don't know what's happening and it looks like it deserves another question.

Comment: Thank you! If subtyping is really just restricted between types with different lifetimes parameters for now (I guess this could change with struct inheritance) I don't need to worry about this because in my case I only deal with things like `i16`, `i32`, `f32`. But I think I still need to wrap my head around the variance stuff for a while.

Comment: If the claim in the documents on these markers were true, you really would need one of the markers; I guess, `InvariantType` would have been the most appropriate one. But given these experimental results I frankly don't know.